# Check if a dictionary contain data true of false, then send a response back

Tags: python, json, django

this is a json response, im getting from my web client view, i'd like to check if this list dictionary contains data or not.How can i go on? Thanks

```
 [
{
    "id": 41,
    "commercialOffice": false,
    "haveStoreRooms": false,
    "workFromHome": false,
    "seperateOffice": false,
    "receptionArea": false,
    "standardInsurance": false,
    "teamAudit": false,
    "auditReport": false,
    "receptionist": false,
    "qualityAssuranceTeam": false,
    "subContractor": null,
    "employeeIdentityCard": false,
    "employeeUniform": false,
    "insuranceList": "",
    "company": null
},
{
    "id": 45,
    "commercialOffice": false,
    "haveStoreRooms": false,
    "workFromHome": false,
    "seperateOffice": false,
    "receptionArea": false,
    "standardInsurance": false,
    "teamAudit": false,
    "auditReport": false,
    "receptionist": false,
    "qualityAssuranceTeam": false,
    "subContractor": null,
    "employeeIdentityCard": false,
    "employeeUniform": false,
    "insuranceList": "0",
    "company": 71
},
{
    "id": 46,
    "commercialOffice": true,
    "haveStoreRooms": true,
    "workFromHome": false,
    "seperateOffice": false,
    "receptionArea": false,
    "standardInsurance": true,
    "teamAudit": false,
    "auditReport": false,
    "receptionist": false,
    "qualityAssuranceTeam": false,
    "subContractor": null,
    "employeeIdentityCard": true,
    "employeeUniform": false,
    "insuranceList": "0",
    "company": 68
},

]
```

I was thinking about this

```
def (self):
   dic = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2'],
       'key2':  'value77' }
       values = dic.values()
      'value77' in [x for v in values for x in v if type(v)==list] or 
      'value77' in values
```

Comment: What you want to check? Please post the Question properly.. And to check data in dict you can use IN operator

Comment: I would like to check  , simply if  each keys contain values or not then return a response.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by data. Is it any dict key? Is it a given dict key?

An empty dict is falsey in Python, so just calling [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) on your list should tell you if every dict has at least one key-value pair:

```
>>> all( [ {1:2}, {'A':'B'} ] )
True
>>> all( [ {1:2}, {'A':'B'}, {}, {3:4}] )
False
```

If you want to check if a given key is present in every dict, you could combine a list comprehension with `get`.

Comment: Hi  Eric, Duminil. Please i added more information... yes.i have done.However, is not still solving my problem.

Comment: @Patcho: What do you want to check exactly? The code example doesn't seem to fit your data. Your dict values aren't lists.

Comment: Check my Updated Answer

Comment: @Eric is actually a json pack of data, i'm getting. So i'd like to check if there if every sub class contains data or not, then return  True or   False.

Comment: @Patcho: Do you accept `false` or an empty string as values?

Comment: Yes, that 's the tricky part, i can accept a null value , a Yes or a True

Answer (score 0):

Use the **in** operator:

```
if b in a:
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
>>> 'foo' in a
True
>>> 'spam' in a
False
```

And the one Explained by @Eric Duminil is much better solution for your answer

**Updated as per your request:**

```
dic_3 = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2'],'key2':  '','key3':None }
for key, value in dic_3.iteritems():
    if value is None or value =='':
        print key ,"is Empty"
```

**Output:**

```
key3 is Empty
key2 is Empty
```